# Run ant as a different user

Tags: ant

If i run a task as root, is there a way to detect its being run as root and run certain tasks as a different user.

I have certain tasks that need to run as root but others that just need to run as the current user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like the following to only run certain targets if the current user has a certain name, such as 'root'.

```
<condition property="rootTasksEnabled">
    <equals arg1="${user.name}" arg2="root" />
</condition>

<target name="do-stuff-if-root" if="rootTasksEnabled">
    <echo>Doing root stuff</echo>
</target>
```

As for running Ant as a different user, you could use <exec> with the su command to spawn another Ant process:

```
<target name="do-stuff" depends="do-stuff-if-root, do-other-stuff" />

<condition property="rootTasksEnabled">
    <equals arg1="${user.name}" arg2="root" />
</condition>
<property name="targetToRunAsOtherUser" value="do-stuff-as-other-user" />
<property name="otherUser" value="johnny" />

<target name="do-stuff-if-root" if="rootTasksEnabled">
    <echo>Doing root stuff</echo>

    <exec executable="su">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg value="${ant.home}/bin/ant -buildfile ${ant.file} ${targetToRunAsOtherUser}" />
        <arg value="${otherUser}" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="do-other-stuff">
    <echo>Doing normal build stuff</echo>
</target>

<target name="do-stuff-as-other-user">
    <echo>I am running as ${user.name}</echo>
    <echo>My home is ${user.home}</echo>
</target>
```

This example only works under Unix.  To do this in Windows you could probably use the *runas* command instead of *su*.